# Jasper sub report data alignment issue in main report (CSV format)

Tags: jasper-reports

My requirement for the jasper report is like this.

**A B   C   D   E   F   G**

A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1      G1

A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1      G1

A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1      G1

A1  B1  C1  D1  E1  F1      G1

Col A, B, C & D are string fields 
Col E, F, G is list of string fields.

What I did was,

•   I created the main report with first 4 fields (Col A, B, C & D) and created the column wise sub report for Col E, F& G.

•   Added sub report in the detail band of the main report after column D

•   Main report has both page header & detail band.

•   Sub report has both page header & detail band.
I don't have any issues in getting the data in the excel format. But I am having below 2 issues with the current set up.

1. Sub report data is not printing on the existing data line of the main report instead its printing on the next line
2. Sub report column headers are getting repeated on the main report

I am using Jaspersoft iReport Designer 5.1.0.

Can some help me to fix these issues?